# JSON Schema: Definitions for array items

Tags: arrays, definition, jsonschema

I am trying to define an array element in a JSON Schema. They array contains items from a type that is already defined in the `definitions` section of the schema.

I have tried:

```
"properties": {
    "userId": {"$ref": "#/definitions/userId"},
    "beacons": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/beaconSchema" }
    }
}
```

The `userId` part is parsed with `#/definitions/userId`. The list items, however, ignore the `#/definitions/beaconSchema` and allow any old junk in it.

**How can I use a JSON schema `definition` to parse all items in a JSON array?**

Comment: The schema fragment you posted is correct.  I suggest you look for typos in the `$ref` path and `definitions` property name.  If you don't find the problem there, try posting more of the schema.

Comment: @Jason You're correct, the `additionalProperties` key was missing from the definition. Please write this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Will do.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema fragment you posted is correct. I suggest you look for typos in the `$ref` path and definitions property name. If you don't find the problem there, try posting more of the schema.

Comment: That was it - a missing `additionalProperties` key in the definition. Thanks (and BTW, you have the perfect user name for the question)